# Filter points in vtk unstructured grid by point data attribute

Tags: python, visualization, vtk, paraview

Given a set of points in a vtkUnstructuredGrid, whats the easiest way to extract all points for which a specified point data attribute meets a certain condition and discard the rest?
In my case I want to remove all points where a field is 0 and extract the others.

In Paraview I can do this using the 'Edit > Find Data...' tool and then the 'Extract Selection' Filter, but how can I do this in code in a vtk pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

This is doable with a Programmable Filter in ParaView.

Find some examples here :
https://www.paraview.org/Wiki/Python_Programmable_Filter

You will need to process you input and recreate your output point by point.